# What does "⌅" symbol mean?

Tags: macos, textmate

I know this is a horribly simplistic question, but.... what does this key symbol mean: [image]

And I have a valid reason for asking... Textmate says it's a shortcut key and I can't figure out how to trigger it other than via mouse-menus :)

Comment: Should probably be migrated to http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

⌅ is enter, which is not the same as return (↩): http://blog.macromates.com/2007/textmates-many-key-shortcuts/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's "Enter" (not to be confused with "Return").